# Wrapping text in input for print.css

Tags: css

Kind of a weird question.

I am working on some print.css and I have come across a situation where I need to word wrap input fields to display all the text in them.

I have tried

```
width: 100% !important;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
```

all variations of above and combinations of above and have had no luck.

My form looks like this.

[image]

The full text in the input is 
"this is a very long ass name that it will never be"

Is there something I am missing? I cannot lengthen the width of the form, nor the fields. They are at their max capacity. I also cannot shorten the "payee name" label.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do better in asking questions, given you're an old member

Comment: @zazvorniki any updates in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using only CSS.

My first approach would be to use a textarea instead of an input and disable line breaks.

```js
$('textarea').on( 'input', function(){
  $(this).val( $(this).val().replace( /[\r\n\v]+/g, '' ) );
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px; /* Just for the demo */
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media print {
  textarea {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: normal;

    height: 3em; /* 3 rows */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</textarea>

<!-- For Demonstration Purposes Only -->
<button onclick="javascript:window.print()">Print</button>
```

If you still want to use an input then I would bind the `input` event, clone the content to a hidden div, and then show it with the print.css file.

```js
let $input = $('input'),
    $clone = $('#clone');

$clone.text( $input.val() );

$input.on( 'input', function(){
  let value = $(this).val();
  $clone.text( value );
});
```

```css
.show-on-print {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .hide-on-print {
    display: none;
  }

  .show-on-print {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="hide-on-print" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit">
<div id="clone" class="show-on-print"></div>

<!-- For Demonstration Purposes Only -->
<button onclick="javascript:window.print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the inputs to be textareas. There are many on the page and come in dynamically based on what the user selects. I can also unfortunately not do the div switch trick which I would do normally because I have been constrained to use css only.